# path separator across os platforms

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, operating-system, temp

from nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdtemp_prefix_callback) on fs.mkdtemp

```
const tmpDir = '/tmp';
const subdir = '/com.domain.app';

!fs.existsSync(tmp + subdir) ? fs.mkdirSync(tmp + subdir) : null;

// This method is *CORRECT*:
const path = require('path');
fs.mkdtemp(tmpDir + path.sep + subdir + path.sep, function(err, folder){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(folder);
});
```

My question is related to `path.sep` and temp directories and I want the code to be platform agnostic, and to be able to run on multiple platforms.

1. what will be the value of `path.sep` across all nodejs platforms.
2. what is the value of tmp directory across all nodejs platforms.
3. is `/tmp` available on windows?
4. any suggestions for above code when it comes to temp directories/paths

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.tmpDir` and `path.join` functions for cross platform code.

```
var tmp = require('os').tmpDir();
var dest = path.join(tmp, "com.domain.app");

!fs.existsSync(dest) ? fs.mkdirSync(dest) : null;
```

Reference. [Writing cross platform node](http://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/)