# path.dirname() with windows path returns just a dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, electron

I am building a Vue JS application inside electron JS. On Unix operating systems, it works perfectly fine, but on Windows, I facing the problem that `path.dirname()` always returns just a dot `.`.

so:

```
path.dirname("C:\Users\zourn\Dropbox\Lindwurm\modsort\TCGA-DU-7294\la_t1c.nii.gz")
```

returns: `.`

to make it weirder:

```
      var os = require("os");

      console.log(os.type()); // clearly shows a windows operating system
```

however:

```
console.log(path.sep)
```

outputs: `/` and not the expected `\`. Therefore, the returned `.` should be kind of expected.

What is going on there? I am using node v14 LTS.

My very ugly solution for the moment is:

```
var definitelyPosix = srcFile.split("\\").join("/");
path.dirname(definitelyPosix)
```

but there must be a better way?

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578002/all-backslashes-are-being-removed-from-local-file-path

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175591/path-separator-across-os-platforms . Not sure what's the problem with Electron/Node but path separator shouldn't affect how it works. I removed the dupe because it may solve the problem but doesn't address the question completely. "I am using node v14 LTS" - so is it Electron or Node?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like `path` is misidentifying the platform for some reason, but if that's the only problem you can force it by using `path.win32.dirname()`.

(assuming your lack of escaped slashes in your first example was just an accident or for illustration purposes)

Comment: from my naive understanding `path.win32.dirname()` was only added with later node versions?

Comment: well you didn't specify your Electron version but I just did a quick test in an Electron 12 project (Node 14.16) and `path.win32.dirname()` is def available